# Why do we add an 'um' here?

Tags: preposition, sentence-structure, grammar-identification

I came across this sentence today:

> Sie besitzen nicht die Berechtigung, um in diesem
> Ordner einen Eintrag zu erstellen

from what I understand, 'um' means something like 'in order to'. But here 'in order to' does not fit. Then why do we need an 'um' here? Is it correct to say the following?

> Sie besitzen nicht die Berechtigung, einen Eintrag in diesem Ordner zu
> erstellen

Comment: I don't get why you think that 'in order to' is an inappropriate translation here or doesn't fit.

Comment: @planetmaker The sentence 'you don't have the authorization in order to create an entry in this file' just sounds very strange. 'You don't have the authorization to create an entry in this file' sounds much better.

Comment: The "um + infinitiv group" (zu erstellen) here is equivalent to "für+noun", i.e. "Berechtigung für das Erstellen eines Eintrages". It is correct that the sentence is also clear without the "um". For my feeling, with "um" is a bit colloquial and without "um" is more elegant.

Comment: @planetmaker, in English, "in order to" refers back to the verb/predicate. "You have authorization in order to create an entry" sounds like someone is explaining why you have authorization (i.e. we've given you authorization; we've done that with the purpose of enabling you to create an entry) rather than being a description of the authorization itself. The negative version "you don't have authorization in order to make an entry" is very weird/confusing, and if you took it very seriously, you might interpret it to mean that your lack of authorization is what enables you to create an entry.

Answer (score 5):

*Um* introduces adverbial clauses with a final meaning (specifying a purpose, *to what end?*).

> Er sprach lauter, um gehört zu werden.

Without an introducing conjunction, infinitival clauses serve as subjects or objects ([complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)); *Ergänzungen* in German).

> Sie versprach, sich um das Problem zu kümmern.

Note that *sie versprach* by itself would be incomplete, missing an object, whereas *er sprach lauter* is completely fine.

<sup>With the unfortunate effect of blurring this very clear distinction, old-fashioned or literary language sometimes allows infinitival clauses without an introducing conjunction to be used adverbially: *Ich bin hier, euch zu bitten …*</sup>

Some nouns are just like verbs (such as *versprechen*) in that they can combine with infinitival clauses as complements.

> das Versprechen, sich um das Problem zu kümmern
> die Energie, den Nachmittag zu überstehen
> die Berechtigung, die Datei zu löschen

These nouns are *relational* in that a promise is a promise of something, energy is energy to do something, etc. They allow complement clauses and complement clauses don't have *um*. That is what makes

> die Berechtigung, um die Datei zu löschen

sound strange. For the final clause to make sense one would have introduce some middle term such as *nötig sein*.

> die Berechtigung (die nötig ist) um die Datei zu löschen

In fact, I find

> die nötige Berechtigung, um die Datei zu löschen

completely acceptable; the notion of necessity introduced by *nötig*  is compatible with a final clause (necessary *for what purpose?).*

Comment: Yes, but there is no *nötige* in the original sentence. With *nötige Berechtigung* I would also find the *um* acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

*Um … zu* most times means *in order to* but in some contexts it means *so as to*. This is such a context.

You can write that example with or without *um*, as you could leave out a *so as* in English.

Comment: Does it mean that 'Sie besitzen nicht die Berechtigung, in diesem Ordner einen Eintrag zu erstellen' is also correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "so as to" wouldn't work in English here: "You do not have permission to create an entry in this folder." There's no grammatical way to fit "so as to" (or "in order to") in this. You might say something like "You need the proper permissions in order to create an entry in this folder, and you don't have them." I'm thinking the German is kind of implying this without all those extra words, and that's where the "um" comes from. Either that or it's just one of those unexplainable mismatches between German and English.

Comment: @Dennis: yes, that would also be correct, but it would mean something different: Consider *you need this right to be able to create directories* and *you need this right in order to create directories*. One states a fact ("right=ability"), the other states a cause.

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right. The *um* sounds very strange for my native ears and should be left out.

I think people use it this way sometimes, because they think it's higher register and you could argue that it isn't totally wrong.

> Sie benötigen Schreibrechte, um einen Eintrag in diesem Ordner zu erstellen.

but

> Sie besitzen nicht die Berechtigung, einen Eintrag in diesem Ordner zu erstellen.

Comment: This is completely wrong! "benötigen ... um" expresses a causal relationship, "besitzen" does not. Your second example just states a fact. Look up "Finalsatz" in the grammar book of your choice or read @DavidVogts (excellent) answer.

Comment: @bakunin Nothing of what you say contradicts my answer. Read David Vogts (excellent) answer again!

Comment: I did. "introduces adverbial clauses with a final meaning", "final" in the (latin-derived) meaning "towards a goal". This is why the "um zu" is the way to signify the *Finalsatz* as *Finalsatz*. Otherwise it would be another type of  *Relativsatz*